# how to secure Sensitive logic and data in angular2 + microservices?

Tags: angular, security, microservices

I'm using microservices + angular2 platform and I want to hide my Service access usernames, passwords and other sensitive data from front end. is there way to hide sensitive codes from front end in Angular2 than minifying or uglifying code?

Comment: This is not the way you secure your app. You should assume that users can decompile or reverse engineer the frontend.

Comment: Yes, I Agree with you. minifying or uglifying is not the solution. then what is the way of doing this?

Comment: You authenticate the user then every action that it sends to the backend/microservice is authorized/checked by the backend.

Comment: Authentication means to identify WHO is doing something. Authorization means to check if that user is permitted to do what he wants.